# python sched cancel thread

Tags: python, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I use Python 3.4 and 3.6. I use `sched.scheduler` for future events at typical 1 hour interval. I run the scheduler in threading.Thread so it is non-blocking.

I run a second threading.Thread that monitors each 5 seconds a global    parameter `_busy`. This parameter can be set to False with `reset()` at global level.

On "reset", all remaining events in the scheduler are cancelled.
Finally I use `.join()` on both threads as cleanup.
However the thread with the scheduler waits for the next (cancelled) scheduler event before it exits. This may be after that hour interval.

How can I force `sched.scheduler` to "update" itself after cancelling all events, so that it becomes finished and the scheduler thread exits?

```
import threading
import time
import sched
import winsound

def ScheduleSound(*args):
    ''' Beep as demo for slowscan '''
    winsound.Beep(args[-1], 500)

class SlowScanSchedule(object):
    '''
        Main interface for slow scan schedule i.e.
        - read and store content of ini-file
        - add actions to schedule
        - start schedule and schedule monitor thread
        Example:
            eggs = SlowScanSchedule("slowscan01.ini")
            eggs.start()
            eggs.schedule.queue
            eggs._monitorthread.isAlive()
            eggs._schedulethread.isAlive()
            eggs.reset() # abort schedule ... takes some time
    '''
    def __init__(self, filename, **kwargs):
        self.schedule = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
        # self.slowscan = omiconfig.IniFile(filename=filename)
        # demo entries for starttime and schedule
        self.timestart = time.mktime(time.localtime())
        self.slowscan = [[10, 7, 1500], [10, 42, 1500], [10, 8, 1500], \
                    [300, 34, 1500], [300, 9, 1500], [300, 67, 1500]]
        self._monitorthread = None
        self._schedulethread = None
        self._busy = False
        # removed all logging for demo
        self._update()
    def _update(self):
        '''fill scheduler'''
        self.reset() # reset scheduled tasks
        previousdelay = 0.0
        for exposevalues in self.slowscan:
            self._add(previousdelay, ScheduleSound, *exposevalues)
            previousdelay += exposevalues[0]
    def _add(self, secondsdelay, executeobject, *executeargs):
        '''Auxiliary: add actions to schedule'''
        self.schedule.enterabs(self.timestart + secondsdelay,
                               1,
                               executeobject,
                               argument=(executeargs))
    def reset(self):
        '''Stop thread with scheduler'''
        self._busy = False
        if self._monitorthread is not None:
            self._monitorthread.join()
            self._schedulethread.join()
        self._monitorthread = None
        self._schedulethread = None
    def start(self):
        '''Start schedule and monitor threads'''
        if self._monitorthread is not None:
            try:
                self.reset()
            except:
                self._monitorthread = None
                self._schedulethread = None
        self._schedulethread = ScheduleThread(self.schedule)
        self._monitorthread = MonitorThread(self)

class MonitorThread(threading.Thread):
    '''Auxiliary object for scheduler monitor inside thread'''
    def __init__(self, monitor):
        '''Create and start thread for scheduler monitor'''
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._lock = threading.Lock()
        self.monitor = monitor
        self.monitor._busy = True
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        '''Non-blocking thread that monitors global _busy and schedule'''
        while self.monitor._busy and not self.monitor.schedule.empty():
            time.sleep(5)
        self._lock.acquire()
        while not self.monitor.schedule.empty():
            self.monitor.schedule.cancel(self.monitor.schedule.queue[-1])
        self._lock.release()
        self.monitor._busy = False

class ScheduleThread(threading.Thread):
    '''Auxiliary object for scheduler inside thread'''
    def __init__(self, schedule, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.schedule = schedule
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        self.schedule.run(blocking=True)
```

Comment: It seems that my function is not possible with (standard) sched. With timer.sleep as the delayfunc() (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html), it will be "at sleep" until next event. I have build another version that checks each second if it has to execute a scheduled function or if it has been canceled.